# convert movie file to bitmap files with DirectShow

Tags: bitmap, ffmpeg, directshow, movie

I want to convert movie files like AVI, MOV etc. to Bitmap-Files, like JPEG, JPEG2000, TIFF etc.
Is it possible to realize that with DirectX / DirectShow?
Is AVCodec from ffmpeg the much more better choice?
Is it well documented?
Are there any other possibilities to realize this problem (f.e. with Qt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a filter graph in DirectShow using the sample grabber filter. This graph will demultiplex and decompress the file and deliver the uncompressed frames to your application via a callback on the sample grabber filter. In this callback, you can save the uncompressed frame as a bitmap or convert it to jpeg using a library like GDI+ or the IJG library.

G